# c++ Template function to flatten a vector of vector

Tags: c++, templates, vector

I wrote a template function to flatten two level nested vector of vector. The second level vector however could be another vector, unique_ptr to vector, or shared_ptr to vector.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>> f1;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>>> f2;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> f3;
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>> f4;
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>> f5;
std::vector<std::vector<std::string>> f6;
```

I wrote this code which works [view on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6274ce43bffd626)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template<typename T>
const T* to_pointer(const T& e) {
    return &e;
}

template<typename T>
const T* to_pointer(const std::unique_ptr<T>& e) {
    return e.get();
}

template<typename T>
const T* to_pointer(const std::shared_ptr<T>& e) {
    return e.get();
}

template <typename T, typename K,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_same<K, std::unique_ptr<std::vector<T>>>::value or
        std::is_same<K, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<T>>>::value or
        std::is_same<K, std::vector<T>>::value
    >::type
>
std::vector<T> flatten(std::vector<K>& source) {
    std::vector<T> result;
    size_t size = 0;
    for (const auto& e : source) {
        size += to_pointer(e)->size();
    }
    result.reserve(size);

    for (const auto& e : source) {
        auto ptr   = to_pointer(e);
        auto begin = ptr->begin();
        auto end   = ptr->end();
        std::copy(begin, end, std::back_inserter(result));
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, would like check if there is better way to write the same code. Appreciate your time and effort.

Comment: Might be a better fit for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Thomas sure thanks, was not aware of it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wish to simplify your code, you can use the [`std::accumulate`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) with custom operation as follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> foo {
        { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 }
    };

    auto bar = std::accumulate(foo.begin(), foo.end(), decltype(foo)::value_type{},
            [](auto& dest, auto& src) {
        dest.insert(dest.end(), src.begin(), src.end());
        return dest;
    });
}
```

The disadvantage of my example is that it won't reserve the space for new elements but reallocates it when necessary.

---

My first example only applies to types which has member type `value_type` which has member function `insert`. This means that `foo` cannot be e.g. an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>>`.

The mentioned problem can be solved by using [SFINAE](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae) on two function templates as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename = typename T::value_type>
T flatten(const std::vector<T>& v) {
    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), T{}, [](auto& dest, auto& src) {
        dest.insert(dest.end(), src.begin(), src.end());
        return dest;
    });
}

template<typename T, typename = typename T::element_type::value_type>
typename T::element_type flatten(const std::vector<T>& v) {
    using E = typename T::element_type;

    return std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), E{}, [](auto& dest, auto& src) {
        dest.insert(dest.end(), src->begin(), src->end());
        return dest;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. It was good to know about std::accumulate, since I never used it before. 

However, this code does not work with 
    `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>>` or with `shared_ptr` for that matter.

Comment: You're welcome! I also extended my answer with support of types like `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::vector<int>>>`.